# run Angular 4 + node API at a time

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am new for angular and I have requirements to develop a web application with Angular4(Front) + REST API using node js(API connectivity with Ms Sql).

Now my confusion is that is it better if I develop both projects separately or not...?

Personally, I prefer to develop both projects separately.

But I am using the visual studio code as my IDE and with visual studio code, I am able to work only one project at a time.

I want to work on both projects at a time.

Is there any way/any other IDE which can help me out? Or
Is there any way to run two projects at a time in visual studio code...?(I have researched a lot for that but I didn't find any helpful solutions)

Comment: Did you use [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to create the Angular project?

Comment: Yes I am using Angular CLI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular CLI has a [development proxy configuration option](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy) that can be used to intercept calls to a development back-end and route them to the API. This can allow you to work on the projects independently as well as taking advantage of `@angular/cli` tools.

You'd create a file called `proxy.conf.json` at the same level as your `angular-cli.json` file. Let's say your node API in development runs on port **3000** at `http://localhost:3000` and your API endpoints are **all** under path "/api", the contents of `proxy.conf.json` would look like:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

You can set up as many intercepts as you need, in this case it would only intercept calls made to "/api" and direct them towards the project running at `http://localhost:3000`.

You would then need to modify your`npm start` in `package.json` of the angular app command to utilize the proxy:

```
"scripts": {
   ...
   "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
   ...
},
```

Then you would just need to run both the back-end and front-end separately in different command windows. You can use a library such as [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run multiple commands in development with a single `npm start`. You'd set up your `npm start` command in the base node API project something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"./bin/www\" \"cd public && npm start\"",
}
```

In this example, my node (express) app is activated from `./bin/www` and my Angular app is located in the `public` folder, but that could obviously be different folder depending on your project structure. You're start could be simpler if the backend node api is just a single entry file `"start": "concurrently \"node ./server.js" \"cd public && npm start\""`.

**Sample structure:**

```
Project
    server.js (back-end node API)
    package.json (concurrently library and command added here)
    public (angular front-end app)
        src
        .angular-cli.json
        package.json (npm start updated to use proxy)
        proxy.conf.json (proxy configuration goes here)
```

Comment: Your solution looks promising... let me try with that.

Comment: Hey Alex, is it possible if I want to use the only proxy not concurrently?

Comment: When I am trying to call with Proxy I am getting Error like "Error occurred while trying to proxy to: localhost:4200/api/[apiFunctionName]"

Comment: I think I know what might be going on. What localhost port is your Node API running on in development? Also in your `proxy.conf.json` what `"target"` do you have?

Comment: I have port 3000 for Node API running and also same port for target in proxy.conf.json

Comment: I get that error if only the @angular/cli project is running as the node API would is unreachable. Try having two console windows open, start/run the Node API in one and `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --open` at the base of the @angular/cli project in the other window.

Comment: @Alex...got the issue and resolved it....Followed your all steps...It's working now for me...Thanks for the help.:)

Comment: Do you have any idea how we can Deploy this combination of application on IIS server?

Comment: You may want to submit a separate question for IIS configuration and rewrites (SPA), but for sure you'd NOT be using this proxy. In terms for Node configuration, you'd serve "index.html" within the "dist" folder (put into public or static folder) generated by @angular/cli. You'd use a rule like `app.use('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist', 'index.html')));`. That will tell Node to load `index.html` if no other request/api paths matched. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/789/getting-started-with-angular-2#t=201708091429077999923)